# backup flashdrive

Tags: windows, macos, usb, backup, usb-flash-drive

Is there a utility I can use that will take a backup of my flash drive every time I insert it into the computer with out me having to take any action?

I would prefer something that runs on Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 5):

I also recommend SyncBack. I think the difficult part of your question is how to auto-start the backup on inserting the USB card/stick.

You could follow [this tutorial on  the SyncBack Knowledgebase](http://www.2brightsparks.com/help/index.php?action=kb&article=233) which shows how to run SyncBack from an external storage device. Create autorun.inf file and let the SyncBack exe start with your backup profile.

Comment: +1 on the autorun, I should look into that myself

Answer (score 4):

[Copied from my own question](https://superuser.com/questions/7820/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-a-folder-synchronized-with-my-usb-drive). Though you do have to schedule or start the syncing, but for the rest it doesn't really require any more attention after you set it up.

Else check this topic: [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)

> You could run a freeware
>   synchronization program. I've used
>   [SyncBack (freeware)](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/) and I'm very
>   happy with it. I use it to synchronize
>   some folders to as NAS at home.

[image]

> Or use [SyncToy](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&DisplayLang=en#QuickInfoContainer) from Microsoft in
>   the past - although do note that
>   version 2.0 does have issues with
>   syncing to NAS devices.

Comment: Nice to see you're happy with SyncBack!

Comment: Haha you wrote it? It was literally quoted from my own question, BUT I did install and used it myself. Does exactly what I needed, so yes I do like it myself as well!

Comment: Well, Ivo, we found a way to send each other instant messages adding comments to our answers. :-)

Comment: Now I'm going to post a question on how to steal rep from you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I use [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52) which is a free application from Microsoft. it has a pretty slick UI and is also accessible from the command line which makes it easy to automate syncs from Windows Task scheduler

Answer (score 1):

I remember one called USBFlashCopy that would launch on connecting the drive. I'm on a phone so I can't link, but it is a good piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

I use the free DirSync pro. 
http://directorysync.sourceforge.net/

I suspect it will work in Mac as well as windows.

Rather than take a backup I synchronize to a directory on my home computer. I've written an AHK script to ensure that this only happens on the machines I want it to. I then compiled the AHK script and call it in autorun.inf