# Solution to sync folders between two computers and a NAS

Tags: windows-7, networking, sync, nas

At work we have two computers and a network attached storage device (NAS) each with a copy of the same folder.

I need a solution that will keep each computer's copy of that folder and the copy of the folder on the NAS in sync.

They used to have a free program that accomplished this but it seems to be gone now and no one remembers what it was called.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to keep a folder synchronized with my USB drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/7820/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-a-folder-synchronized-with-my-usb-drive)

Comment: It's about syncing a folder, and practically every answer on there will work to sync to a network location.  Basically, pick a program that Sync's and use it.  If you're just asking us to suggest a program that does this, then that wold be off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using **Robocopy**. I doubt it is the best solution, but it is built into Windows 7. For your scenario you would be looking at the:

```
 Repeated Copy Options
            /MON:n : MONitor source; run again when more than n changes seen.
            /MOT:m : MOnitor source; run again in m minutes Time, if changed.
```

However, maybe add some details what purpose this data serves. There might be solutions that address various issues that could result from this, depending on what you use this data for. Also I don't know how much load this monitoring puts on the NAS.

Full list of parameters:
http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll keep it in mind if I can't find another more efficient solution.

Comment: You're welcome, tag it as "useful for all sorts of remote copying tasks", the robo stands for robust. ;-)