# How to synchronise USB key with hard drive folder?

Tags: windows, usb, sync

I have a USB key for which I want, each time it is inserted in a computer, to have its content synchronized (both ways) with one folder on the machine.

- The synchronization process should be started as soon as the USB key is inserted
- The folder should be configured based upon the computer on which the key synchronizes (typically through a wizard/dialog, but no config file edition)
- The synchronization process should graciously stop when USB key is unplugged

**Do you know if a synchronization software with those features exist ? ANd is there any tutorial on how to setup such a solution ?**

I've thought about using softwares such as FreeFileSync, but it seems to lack the ability to start/stop synchronization when USB is inserted/removed/ Maybe I've not found the right configuration tutorial ...

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ indeed, topic is quite similar ... But the mentionned solution does not seems polished enough to my mind.

Comment: Also: [What is the best way to keep a folder synchronized with my USB drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/7820/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-a-folder-synchronized-with-my-usb-drive?rq=1)